# sudo: port: command not found; mac os x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am trying to build a todo list with Ruby and Ruby on Rails. In my rails application I add the gems I need and then type 'bundle' in my terminal. Everything works until:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /Users/Misha/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
```

I go to the link provided and for mac it instructs to do the following commands:

```
sudo port install libxml2 libxslt

sudo gem install nokogiri
```

but then i get the command not found. I tried following a similar problem and solution:

```
sudo vi /etc/paths

Add 2 following lines:

/opt/local/bin

/opt/local/sbin
```

but still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you using fink, macports, darwinports, or homebrew?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `sudo port install libxml2 libxslt` is failing because you don't have the [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) package manager installed. However, I would install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead (which is my personal package manager preference):

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`

Then continue with the [instructions provided in the error message](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html), substituting `brew` for `sudo port`:

`brew install libxml2 libxslt`

if that works, try:

`sudo gem install nokogiri`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer of @thohl that I totally agree. Nokogiri sometimes is difficult to install. For that reason I keep the following recipe:

```
cd $( brew --prefix )
git checkout 763d946 Library/Formula/libxml2.rb
brew unlink libxml2
brew install libxml2 libxslt
git checkout master Library/Formula/libxml2.rb

ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install nokogiri --verbose -- --with-xslt-dir=$( brew --prefix )/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-iconv dir=$( brew --prefix )/Cellar/libiconv/1.14 --with-xml2-include=$( brew --prefix )/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=$( brew --prefix )/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/lib --use-system-libraries
```

These incantations made the trick in my case